# How do I apply Post's crieterion to check if given function is functionally complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was reading about [Post's crieterion](https://victoramelkin.com/ta/cs40/posts-criterion.pdf) to prove whether given function is [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) or not.

I came cross function $f(a,b)=a'+b$. I tried determining whether this function is functionally complete or not as follows:

> $f(0,0)=1→$ **Not zero preserving**
>   $f(1,1)=0→$ **Not one preserving**
>   [image]
>   As can be seen from above truth table, odd number of 1s can cause both $f=0$ and $f=1$. Hence $f$ is **not linear**.
>   $f'(a',b')=(a+b')'=a'b≠f→$ **Not self-dual**.
>   Also from below Hassee diagram, it can be seen that the function is **not monotone** (as $f(0,0)=1$, but $f(1,0)=0$.):
>   [image]
>   According to Post, a system of boolean functions is functionally complete if and only if this system does not entirely belong to any of above properties.
>   $f$ is the only function in given system and it does not posses any of those properties. Hence $f$ is functionally complete.

However, I was referring text which says following:

> $f(a,0)=a'$
>   So to obtain complement of variable $a$, we need to set other variable $b=0$. So, we need to take help of 0. $f$ cannot emulate negation without the help of boolean constant 0. Hence its not functionally complete, but partially functionally complete.

Now I am confused. Does Post's criteria fail to address partial functional completeness. Or text is incorrect and no such concept of partial functional completeness exist?

Comment: If I am reading correct, it is not true that $f(1, 1) = 0$. In fact $f(1, 1) = 1$, so $f$ is 1-preserving.

Comment: Yikes..silly mistake. My bad. Just want to know if my approach correct. Can any function be tested for functional completeness like this? Also does Post say anything about partial functional completeness?